# MS Word regex insert carriage return in match

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

It appears that MS Word accepts regular expressions for finding and replacing strings. I would like to use regex to add carriage returns to a block of text, in order to parse out individual lines.

starting text:

6. (Previously Presented): something here 9. (Previously Presented):other thing here 12. (Previously Presented): another example 16. (Previously Presented): more text

desired end text:

6. (Previously Presented): something here
7. (Previously Presented):other thing here
8. (Previously Presented): another example
9. (Previously Presented): more text

I have succeeded in getting MS Word to match the desired strings with the following expression

[0-9]{1,2}\. \(

however, I haven’t been able to write a proper matching string that modifies the match and adds two carriage returns. I have tried all of these with no success:

^p^p\1

^p^p\0

^p^p$0

^p^p$1

^p^p$&

the closest I can get returns a result like this, with all the numbers deleted.

Previously Presented): something here

Previously Presented):other thing here

Previously Presented): another example

Previously Presented): more text

Please let me know if I have overlooked something, and if this is actually possible in Word.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Word doesn't accept `^p` in regular expressions, you need to use `^13` instead. So your replace with field will be: `^13^13\1`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I tested both ^p and ^13, which provide the same result. to clarify, I'm having trouble with the "\1" part of the replace expression. Word deletes it entirely, but I need it to be included in the replace text.

Comment: \1 backreference only part of the find expression, especially the one within the first pair of brackets. If you don't have brackets it will not put anything. Try to match `([0-9]{1,2}\. \()`